# Using python, how to write new item into a new row in a CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, xlsx

Form a Microsoft xlsx file, I am reading a column containing house addresses using a python script. And then, I want to write it into a CSV file in a format like below:

```
firstname_user, secondname_user, address
firstname_user, secondname_user, address
firstname_user, secondname_user, address
firstname_user, secondname_user, address
```

Below the python script I have to do this

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

the_xl_file = "mydata.xlsx"

original_xl = pd.ExcelFile(the_xl_file).parse('Sheet1')
address_list=[]
address_list.append(original_xl['column_name'])
 
file = open('output.csv', 'w+', newline ='') 

first_name = "John"
second_name = "Doe"

with file:     
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file) 
    for address in address_list:
        # How can I switch to a new row here?
        csv_writer.writerow(first_name + ',' + second_name + ',' + address)

print(' CSV file created with addresses ... ')
```

**Question:**
Above script works. The only only problem is that all the addresses are written into one row. That does not comply to the format. I want to write each item in a new row so that every new row contains first_name followed by last_name followed by address.

And additional problem is that it gets double quotes around each item like this - "John,Doe,AddressLine1". How can I eliminate or ignore the "?

**Environment:**
Python 3.9.0 on macOS Catalina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

writerow function in csv module will take one parameter and that should be in **list** type.
change the write logic like this.

```
with open('output.csv', 'w+', newline ='') output_file:     
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file) 
    for address in address_list:
        csv_writer.writerow([first_name, second_name, address])
```